# like and dislike only once php JS mySQL

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, voting

I'm currently stumped on a problem. I'm trying to add like and dislike buttons for a displayed video, however, the user can only like it once and not multiple times. I'm getting the following errors,

> Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE v_id='34'' at line 1

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

if( !empty( $_GET['$v_id'] ) ){

    $vid = $_SESSION['v_id'] = $_GET['$v_id'];

$sql='SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id=?';
    $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $vid );
    $res=$stmt->execute();
    if( $res ){
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $videoname );
        $stmt->fetch();

        printf('
            <video width="70%%" height="70%%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
                <source src="uploads/%s" type="video/mp4" id="vid">
            </video>
        ', $videoname );
    }
} else {
    exit('missing ID');
}
$lk = mysqli_query($link, "SELECT likes FROM video WHERE v_id='$vid'");
$likeCount = 0;
$sumlk = ($lk + $likeCount);
$liked = mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO video(likes) VALUES('$sumlk') WHERE v_id='$vid'");
?>
<br>
<a href="#" onclick="like(event)"><img src="imageStoring/like.png" style="height:30px;" /></a><?php echo '$liked'; ?>
<img src="imageStoring/dislike.png" style="height:30px;"/>

<?php
$func = <<<EOD
<script type="text/javascript">
function like(event){
'$likeCount' = 1;
}
</script>
EOD;
?>
```

Below is the mySQL,

```
CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
likes INT,
dislikes INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NILL
);
```

Comment: And what have you tried to solve it? Obviously, you cannot use the result of `mysqli_query` in an addition

Comment: A `WHERE` clause doesn't make sense in an `INSERT` statement.  Refer back to the manual for `INSERT` syntax: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert.html  Or were you looking to perform an `UPDATE` instead?  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html

Comment: If `v_id` is an INT, I'm thinking you don't want the single quotes around it, that will treat it like a string.

Answer (score 1):

`mysqli_query` returns a result object. In this result object you can use methods like `fetch_assoc()` to get the actual rows and columns you're requesting.

Answer (score 1):

if you want change  the value where  v_id  =  you_actula value 
you should use an  update and not an insert

```
   UPDATE video 
   set likes = '$sumlk'
   WHERE v_id='$vid'
```

any way you should not use php var in sql  you should use prepared statement and binding param as in your first select

Comment: I switched from using an insert to an update like you said. However the like only stays at one for all accounts that liked it. I'm also still getting this error;  Notice: Object of class mysqli_result could not be converted to int

Comment: The error because you are trying to echo the result for mysqli_result  ..with  `<?php echo '$liked'; ?>`  .. the result for the query is not a number but an objet  .. you should take a look at php  mysqli_query